# Assign vs anything etc Viewunload viewload etc

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective-c.

I have 2 unrelated questions.

- What is the process that you have to go through when creating an instance variable or property? For example, I usually define the variable in the interface section, then create a property for it, then synthesize it, then set it to nil in the viewUnload section.

Do I have to define the variable in the interface section even though I create a property for it? When do I have to set the variable to nil in the viewUnload section?

- What is the difference between strong, weak, non-atomic, atomic, assign, etc when defining properties? When should I strong, weak, non-atomic, atomic, assign, etc?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the process that you have to go through when creating an
>   instance variable or property?

Synthesizing a property is to declare its ivar, and define the accessor methods, not to allocate and initialize it. You need to initialize it at proper point of time, (usually during initialization of the object instance in some `-init*` or right before a view is about to be displayed, e.g. in `-viewDidLoad`).

> What is the difference between strong, weak, non-atomic, atomic, assign, etc when defining
>   properties? When should I strong, weak, non-atomic, atomic, assign, etc?

Strong, weak, assign are modifiers that change the way the object instance is referred. See documents for Automatic Reference Counting.([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) and [Apple's Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html))

Non-atomic and atomic are modifiers that change the way the accessor are synthesized. See the section **Declared Properties** of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW31).

> Do I have to define the variable in the interface section even though I create a property for it?

No. As for now, you do not need to, because the compiler in the latest SDKs would do these for you. For example, if you declared a property: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *data1;`, then you would get ivar `NSData *_data1` for free, even if you omitted the @synthesize statement.

> When do I have to set the variable to nil in the viewUnload section?

No. And BTW, `-viewDidUnload` is deprecated in iOS 6.0.